# How to call or activate a class?

Tags: ruby

In my lib folder I have billede.rb:

```
class Billede
  require 'RMagick'
  #some code that creates a watermark for a image
  image.write(out)
end
```

How do I call/activate the class? Is the only way to change it to a Rake task?

Comment: Is there any doubt about what my question is?

Comment: Yes, there is doubt. I personally don't know what you mean. What is it that you want to do? Why is all that code inside a `class`?

Comment: How do I run the code in my console? When I have a class. Is it necessary to create a rake file instead of a class? To simply run the code in the class?

Comment: The code inside the class should create a watermark on an image.

Comment: I believe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming would be a great start

Comment: I think my question will be helpful for future beginners. I know how to create a rake task. Just thinking of another solution, that may be better. I learn by doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code 'inside a class' is run just like any other code. If you have a Ruby file like this:

```
puts "Hello from #{self}"
class Foo
  puts "Hello from #{self}"
end
```

and you run the file (either via `ruby foo.rb` on the command line or `require "./foo"` or `load "foo.rb"` in a script) it then you will see the output:

> Hello from main
>   Hello from Foo

If you want to load a utility that 'does something' that you can then invoke from a REPL like IRB or the Rails console, then do this:

```
module MyStuff
  def self.do_it
    # your code here
  end
end
```

You can `require "./mystuff"` to load the code, and when you're ready to run it type `MyStuff.do_it`

*And, as you may guess, you can also create methods that accept arguments.*

If you want to define a file that can be included in others (with no immediate side effects) but which also "does its thing" whenever the file is run by itself, you can do this:

```
module MyStuff
  def self.run!
    # Go
  end
end

MyStuff.run! if __FILE__==$0
```

Now if you `require` or `load` this file the `run!` method won't be invoked, but if you type `ruby mystuff.rb` from the command line it will.

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I was looking for. Think it is a better solution than creating a rake task. If you are just gonna test some code.

Answer (score 5):

You can't call a class directly. You have to call a method on that class. For example:

```
class Billede
  def self.foobar
    # some kind of code here...
  end
end
```

Then you can call it via `Billede.foobar`

Perhaps you should read some documentation on basic ruby syntax before trying to do more complex things (such as manipulating images w/ Rmagick).

Comment: +1 for a right answer; you should show how to define such a method, however. Note that just diving in with a focused task is considered by many to be a much more effective way at learning a language than trying to "learn" the language through documentation or tutorials. Some basics are good, but so is experimentation and asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
# in /lib/billede.rb
class Billede

  def self.do_something(arg)
    # ...
  end

  def do_anotherthing(arg)
    # ...
  end

end

# inside a model or controller
require 'billede'

Billede::do_something("arg")
# or
billede_instance = Billede.new
billede_instance.do_anotherthing("arg")
```